# I have to use import * as React from "react" in typescript, otherwise can't recognize the 'react' package of nodemodules

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use import React from "react" in typescript, but I have to use import * as React from "react", otherwise can't recognize the 'react' package of nodemodules

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3337

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try setting `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true` in your ts-config. It will fix the above error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I tried and did this "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
 "module": "ES6", the project started successfully

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong.

The import should be

```
import React from 'react';
```

With a capital **R**

The reason why `import * as react from "react";` works because it specifies that everything should be imported from "react" package and it should be given an alias of `react`.

If you already tried the above import, you can try the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` compiler flag as mentioned [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/5128#issuecomment-270078424).

You can learn more about it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-default-import-interop-with-systemjs)

Comment: You are right, but the problem is not in capitalization. When I use import React from 'react';, can't recognize the 'react' package of nodemodules

Comment: This is the key to the problem.

Comment: Okay. Kindly update the question with capital R so that others might not get confused like me.

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
import React from 'react';
```

doesn't work. I get the following error

> Module ".../node_modules/@types/react/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flagts(1259)
>   index.d.ts(55, 1): This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.

So I'm going with

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Comment: I just want to find a way to support import React from 'react';